# Postgres Update Using Select Passing In Parent Variable

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to update a few thousand rows in my Postgres table using the result of a array_agg and spatial lookup.

The query needs to take the geometry of the parent table, and return an array of the matching row IDs in the other table. It may return no IDs or potentially 2-3 IDs.

I've tried to use an UPDATE FROM but I can't seem to pass into the subquery the parent table geom column for the SELECT. I can't see any way of doing a JOIN between the 2 tables.

Here is what I currently have:

```
UPDATE lrc_wales_data.records
SET lrc_array = subquery.lrc_array

FROM (
    SELECT array_agg(wales_lrcs.gid) AS lrc_array 
    FROM layers.wales_lrcs 
    WHERE st_dwithin(records.geom_poly, wales_lrcs.geom, 0)
) AS subquery

WHERE records.lrc = 'nrw';
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "records"
LINE 7: WHERE st_dwithin(records.geom_poly, wales_lrcs.geom, 0)
```

Is this even possible?

Many thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realised there was no need to use SET FROM. I could just use a sub query directly in the SET:

```
UPDATE lrc_wales_data.records
SET lrc_array = (
    SELECT array_agg(wales_lrcs.gid) AS lrc 
    FROM layers.wales_lrcs 
    WHERE st_dwithin(records.geom_poly, wales_lrcs.geom, 0)
)

WHERE records.lrc = 'nrw';
```